# 1st run after installation ..it gives message SDK missing

Tags: android, android-studio

when I start android studio I start finding SDK automatically and then gives a  message missing SDK

[image: Missibg Image]

[image]

Comment: I don't see any problems in your question. Click next, and it will install you Android SDK

Comment: c/user/username/Appdata/local/android by default at this location sdk is found ..but here in my case it is not there –

Comment: what happens if you just click Next?

Comment: a windows open having title "verify settings" then after clicking "Next" i gives message nothing to do. SDK tool directory is missing then after clicking Finish it come to the home window

Answer (score -1):

open android studio -> go to sdk manager -> set your path of your sdk
i hope it will work

Comment: c/user/username/Appdata/local/android  by default at this location sdk is faund ..but here in my case it is not there

Comment: where you install your sdk?

Comment: i am installing android studio 3.0.1 which has intigerated SDK

Comment: when i was running the setup then in the very begning we have to choose components and here i am getting check boxes only for Android studio and Android virtual device ,not for Android SDK

Comment: check this link and see the video in this link https://developer.android.com/studio/install.html